# Authenticate DDP Client using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, ddp

A node.js DDP client (using [node-ddp](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ddp)) calls a method `insertMessage` on the DDP server, which saves a document to mongodb.

```
Meteor.methods({
    'insertMessage': function(msg) {
        Messages.insert({'msg':msg, 'userId': userId})
    }
})
```

How can we only allow authenticated DDP clients to insert document containing their unique identifier `userId`, and not be able to forge someone else's `userId`? I looked at [ddp-login](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ddp-login) but it seem like successful authentication gives a token, can this token be used for our purpose?

```
Meteor.methods({
    'insertMessage': function(msg) {

        // Check that the current user's userId (how can we do this?)
        userId = getUserId()

        Messages.insert({'msg':msg, 'userId': userId})
    }
})
```

Comment: In methods, [`this.userId`](http://docs.meteor.com/#method_userId) will be the logged in user's user id, or `null`, if the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the server, you have this parameters..

Meteor.methods

> this.userId
>
> this.setUserId
>
> this.isSimulation
>
> this.unblock
>
> this.connection

```
Meteor.methods({
    'insertMessage': function(msg) {
        userId = this.userId;
        Messages.insert({'msg':msg, 'userId': userId})
    }
})
```